# memcacheq ,the message body is not longer enough

Tags: memcached

memcacheq ,the message body is not longer enough,I start with "
memcacheq -u root -d -r -H /data1/memcacheq -N -R -v -L 2048 -B 65530 > /data1/mq_error.log 2>&1"

log show that "larger than database's maximum record length 1024"

but it doesn't work. how can I resize the body length.

Answer (score 0):

According to [multiple documentations](https://github.com/agentzh/memcacheq):

```
    So we have a limit on the message body size with a max of a bit less than *64K*.
```

It doesn't seem like there is a work around for this limitation.

EDIT: [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/memcachedb/message$20body/memcachedb/-jfYGCGzHrQ/vqFTf_JBQUgJ) was provided by one of the authors as a work around for body length, but it really seems that MemcacheQ has a size limitation.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: But when I store a string length of 2048 bytes,It doesn't work. not_stored

Comment: could you try not defining the size in the command invoking memcacheq and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "-A"? It is used to modify the page size of BDB